# /etc/fstab 5th column

Tags: rhel, etc, dump

Whatever I have understood so far about the 5th column of `/etc/fstab` that it is for dump command to run on that file system. if entry is `0` dump command will not run and if the entry is `1` then dump command will run.

But I have not understood yet that in what condition the command will run? And where will be the location of the dump. How we can check that dump ran on that file file system?

Comment: Checking the [`dump(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dump) man page should give you the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *dump* or *fs_freq* column in `/etc/fstab` is the dump frequency in days. It is used by [`dump`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4BSD/usr/man/cat8/dump.8)'s  `-w` and `-W` options  to inform the operator which filesystems need to be dumped. To my knowledge, a 0 in that field never prevented `dump` from running; the filesystem just wouldn't show up in `dump -w` output.

One use case is that the dump operator would run `dump -w` to see what needed to be done that day, then would load the appropriate tapes into the tape drives and run `dump` to do a full or incremental dump for each appropriate filesystem. In practice, most installations I'm familiar with dumped every filesystem every day, so `dump -w` was used just to check if a filesystem was falling through the cracks.

> But I have not understood yet that in what condition the command will run? And where will be the location of the dump.

It doesn't run by default. You have to set something up yourself. You can have it output to a tape if you have one, or to a file. Many people use a higher-level backup system such as [amanda](http://www.amanda.org/) to manage their backups.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Doubt is clear now and I have tried to dump a file system to a file and it worked.