# The fifth field of fstab query

Tags: linux, fstab

In "/etc/fstab" the entries are like this

```
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

The fifth field (0) is used by dump (a backup utility) to decide if a filesystem should be backed up.But if I provide it as "1", then where this backup will be created?

Please accept apologies if I am asking something stupid...

Thanks..

Comment: Read `man dump`....

Comment: the field only provide 'if' not where. where is specified by `-f` ( e.g. `-f -` will dump to stdout).

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182734/etc-fstab-5th-column

Answer (score 3):

That is not working automatically. If you have set 1 to the 5th field in `/etc/fstab` that means nothing yet. First the utillity `dump` must exist on the system (nowadays it's most probably not installed). Second, `dump` must be called manually or at least via `cron`.

Earlier, `dump` was used to make backups on tape drives. An advantage of `dump` was the fact that it operated below the filesystem, so when backuping the access time of files and folders was not changed. `dump` can also print the backup to stdout. So it was also used to pipe the output trough an ssh connection to a backup server.

But, take care when backuping with `dump`. `dump` can safely be used against unmounted and read-only filesystems. On mounted filesystem that are not idle, I wouldn't recommend `dump`.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth field is a **flag** that indicates if this file has to be included during a backup operation using `dump`.

Suppose you use this command:

```
dump -0uf /media/usb1/my_backup /home/newuser/documents
```

It will create a level 0 dump file called `my_backup` on `/media/usb1` with the contents of `/home/newuser/documents` that have the **flag**.